# Persist an average value of all points within a polygon to new field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a polygon Zones layer and a Address points layer.

The following query completes:

```
SELECT zones.OBJECTID, Avg(address.WalkTime)
FROM address
JOIN zones
ON zones.Shape.STContains(address.Shape) = 1
GROUP BY mb.OBJECTID

╔══════════╦════════════════╗
║ OBJECTID ║ No column Name ║
╠══════════╬════════════════╣
║       31 ║ 8.1            ║
║       41 ║ 5.3            ║
║       55 ║ 12.5           ║
║       78 ║ 10.4           ║
║       94 ║ 9.7            ║
╚══════════╩════════════════╝
```

I have a new empty numeric column in Zones called **Avg_WalkTime**

**How do I adapt the query to insert the average value into this column?**

*An attempt:*

```
UPDATE 
    zones 
SET  
    zones.Avg_WalkTime = (
    SELECT Avg(address.WalkTime)
        FROM address
    WHERE zones.Shape.STContains(address.Shape) = 1
```

However, this fails with incorrect syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `GROUP BY` and update at the same time because the rows were grouped and the link to the underlying, original row is "lost".

You can use a CTE or subquery to compute the average, then join back to the original table through a set of columns that correctly identifies a row. I'm assuming that this is the `OBJECTID` for this case.

```
;WITH Averages AS
(
    SELECT 
        zones.OBJECTID, 
        Average = Avg(address.WalkTime)
    FROM 
        address
        JOIN zones ON zones.Shape.STContains(address.Shape) = 1
    GROUP BY 
        zones.OBJECTID
)
UPDATE Z set
    Avg_WalkTime = A.Average
FROM
    zones AS Z
    INNER JOIN Averages AS A ON Z.OBJECTID = A.OBJECTID
```

Another solution using a correlated subquery. This one will update all `zones`, even if there is no matching row on `address` (will set average to `NULL`). The previous one will only update the zones that have at least 1 address (`INNER JOIN`).

```
UPDATE Z SET
    Avg_WalkTime = (SELECT Avg(A.WalkTime) FROM address AS A WHERE Z.Shape.STContains(A.Shape) = 1)
FROM
    zones AS Z
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this now.  I thought it would be simpler.  Could have sworn I saw a sample once that was along the lines of UPDATE Zones SET avg_wt = (SELECT Avg(WalkTime) FROM Address WHERE Zones.Shape.STIntersects = 1 

Will report back in a bit

Comment: The one you mention is similar to the 2nd example I've shown, with the difference that I use a table alias on the update (`UPDATE Z SET...` instead of `UPDATE <tableName> SET...`) as I find it easier to read and eventually expand with a join.

Comment: I get this, which from your answer is expected and desirable.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
I like you approach.  I now need to find the most recurring integer value from a integer field in the point layer per polygon.  Will see if I can take a similar approach, and hopefully not ask another Q!  Big thanks.